# Can a USB hard drive work with only pins 2 and 3 connected to the host?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, power-supply

I want to plug a bus-powered USB disk into a tiny computer which does not have adequate power available (Raspberry Pi). I can solder a USB y-cable, which sends pins 1 and 4 to a separate 5V power supply, and pins 2 and 3 to the host.  Unfortunately, the disk will not mount in this configuration.  Is there some requirement that all 4 pins must connect to the host?

USB Pinout:

[image: USB Pinout]

Comment: A more sensible solution here is a powered USB hub - this would provide power to both the pi and the externalhdd with rev2 onwards.

Comment: Sensible in some cases, but here it would add unwanted bulk.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the Pi requires the USB ground (pin 4) to be connected in addition to the two data pins.
Source: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=487224#p487224

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. The power headers on the Pi (and usb in general) are dummy pins, so there's no logic looking at them. I would check the connections on your power cable and make sure your power adapter is rated for the load the drive is placing on it.

sources:
-http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=47694
-general electronics knowledge

Answer (score 0):

A Raspberry Pi complies to standard USB 2.0 specs and has enough power for a standard 2.5" hard drive to be connected.

Don't treat the Pi different to a regular computer.

I personally wouldn't recommend you start splicing and soldering cables.